# How to Parse nested json using Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I want to parse nested json using retrofit and bind it in recyclerview. Am familiar with **Parsing simple json using Retrofit**. But i dont know how to parse **nested json using retrofit**. i am newbie to retrofit. any help will be appreciated ?

Here is that Link: http://api.wunderground.com/api/356d60036a9374e9/conditions/forecast/alert/q/22.897,88.879.json

JSON DATA :

```
{
  "response": {
  "version":"0.1",
  "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  "conditions": 1
  ,
  "forecast": 1
  }
        ,
    "error": {
        "type": "unknownfeature"
    }
    }
  , "current_observation": {
        "image": {
        "url":"http://icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
        "title":"Weather Underground",
        "link":"http://www.wunderground.com"
        },
        "display_location": {
        "full":"Tentulbaria, India",
        "city":"Tentulbaria",
        "state":"WB",
        "state_name":"India",
        "country":"IN",
        "country_iso3166":"IN",
        "zip":"00000",
        "magic":"608",
        "wmo":"41946",
        "latitude":"22.890000",
        "longitude":"88.870000",
        "elevation":"11.9"
        },
        "observation_location": {
        "full":"Kolkata, ",
        "city":"Kolkata",
        "state":"",
        "country":"IN",
        "country_iso3166":"IN",
        "latitude":"22.64999962",
        "longitude":"88.44999695",
        "elevation":"20 ft"
        },
        "estimated": {
        },
        "station_id":"VECC",
        "observation_time":"Last Updated on February 5, 5:30 PM IST",
        "observation_time_rfc822":"Mon, 05 Feb 2018 17:30:00 +0530",
        "observation_epoch":"1517832000",
        "local_time_rfc822":"Mon, 05 Feb 2018 17:44:32 +0530",
        "local_epoch":"1517832872",
        "local_tz_short":"IST",
        "local_tz_long":"Asia/Kolkata",
        "local_tz_offset":"+0530",
        "weather":"Clear",
        "temperature_string":"81 F (27 C)",
        "temp_f":81,
        "temp_c":27,
        "relative_humidity":"61%",
        "wind_string":"Calm",
        "wind_dir":"North",
        "wind_degrees":0,
        "wind_mph":0,
        "wind_gust_mph":0,
        "wind_kph":0,
        "wind_gust_kph":0,
        "pressure_mb":"1013",
        "pressure_in":"29.92",
        "pressure_trend":"0",
        "dewpoint_string":"66 F (19 C)",
        "dewpoint_f":66,
        "dewpoint_c":19,
        "heat_index_string":"83 F (28 C)",
        "heat_index_f":83,
        "heat_index_c":28,
        "windchill_string":"NA",
        "windchill_f":"NA",
        "windchill_c":"NA",
        "feelslike_string":"83 F (28 C)",
        "feelslike_f":"83",
        "feelslike_c":"28",
        "visibility_mi":"1.7",
        "visibility_km":"2.8",
        "solarradiation":"--",
        "UV":"-1","precip_1hr_string":"-9999.00 in (-9999.00 mm)",
        "precip_1hr_in":"-9999.00",
        "precip_1hr_metric":"--",
        "precip_today_string":"0.00 in (0.0 mm)",
        "precip_today_in":"0.00",
        "precip_today_metric":"0.0",
        "icon":"clear",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_clear.gif",
        "forecast_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/global/stations/41946.html",
        "history_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/VECC/2018/2/5/DailyHistory.html",
        "ob_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=22.64999962,88.44999695",
        "nowcast":""
    }
}
```

In that json data i want to fetch the following json data:

```
"current_observation": {
            "image": {
            "url":"http://icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
            "title":"Weather Underground",
            "link":"http://www.wunderground.com"
            },
```

Comment: Didn't tried GSON FORMAT plugin and JSONTOKOTLINCLASS plugin ?

Comment: Simply create pojo class using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ site  and parse your json.

Answer (score 0):

You can add json convertor to Retrofit and you can parse it.

[Parsing Nested Json](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-mapping-of-nested-objects)

Retrofit best tutorial i have found till now.

[Retrofit complete turoial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client).

This will help you in all your concerns related to Retrofit.

Comment: I know how to parse simple json using retrofit. My problem is parsing complex nested json as i mentioned above.

Comment: for example.
`{
    "age": 26,
    "email": "norman@futurestud.io",
    "isDeveloper": true,
    "name": "Norman",

    "userAddress": {
        "city": "Magdeburg",
        "country": "Germany",
        "houseNumber": "42A",
        "street": "Main Street"
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Create mode like this and in your response type pass the model it will automatically parse the json into model for image data

```
 public class Example {

 @SerializedName("current_observation")
 @Expose
 private CurrentObservation currentObservation;

 public CurrentObservation getCurrentObservation() {
 return currentObservation;
 }

 public void setCurrentObservation(CurrentObservation currentObservation) {
 this.currentObservation = currentObservation;
 }

 public static class CurrentObservation {

    @SerializedName("image")
    @Expose
    private Image image;

    public Image getImage() {
    return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Image image) {
    this.image = image;
    }
 }

 public static class Image {

        @SerializedName("url")
        @Expose
        private String url;
        @SerializedName("title")
        @Expose
        private String title;
        @SerializedName("link")
        @Expose
        private String link;

        public String getUrl() {
        return url;
        }

        public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
        return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
        }

        public String getLink() {
        return link;
        }

        public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
        }

  }

}
```

sample api call

```
  public interface Service {
  @GET("users/info")
  Call<Example> getInfo();
}
```

**Edit:** 
you can call this retrofit function anywhere in your MainActivity and use the data.

```
public void getImageData(){

Call<Example> call = apiService.getInfo();
call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
      //this is how you can use the parsed model
      Example info = response.body();
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
      //handle the error here
  }

}
```

Comment: I have updated the answer, if you are using retrofit then you can call this function anywhere in your MainActivity and get the details.

Answer (score 0):

First, create `Model` i.e `POJO` class to parse your response

It will look something like this

```
package app.com.socket;
/**
 * Created by akshay.katariya on 05-Feb-18.
 */

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Pojo
{

    @SerializedName("response")
    public Response response;
    @SerializedName("current_observation")
    public Current_observation current_observation;

    public static class Features {
        @SerializedName("conditions")
        public int conditions;
        @SerializedName("forecast")
        public int forecast;
    }

    public static class Error {
        @SerializedName("type")
        public String type;
    }

    public static class Response {
        @SerializedName("version")
        public String version;
        @SerializedName("termsofService")
        public String termsofService;
        @SerializedName("features")
        public Features features;
        @SerializedName("error")
        public java.lang.Error error;
    }

    public static class Image {
        @SerializedName("url")
        public String url;
        @SerializedName("title")
        public String title;
        @SerializedName("link")
        public String link;
    }

    public static class Display_location {
        @SerializedName("full")
        public String full;
        @SerializedName("elevation")
        public String elevation;
    }

    public static class Observation_location {
        @SerializedName("elevation")
        public String elevation;
    }

    public static class Estimated {
    }

    public static class Current_observation {
        @SerializedName("image")
        public Image image;
        @SerializedName("display_location")
        public Display_location display_location;
        @SerializedName("observation_location")
        public Observation_location observation_location;
        @SerializedName("estimated")
        public Estimated estimated;
        @SerializedName("nowcast")
        public String nowcast;

        public Image getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public void setImage(Image image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        public Display_location getDisplay_location() {
            return display_location;
        }

        public void setDisplay_location(Display_location display_location) {
            this.display_location = display_location;
        }

        public Observation_location getObservation_location() {
            return observation_location;
        }

        public void setObservation_location(Observation_location observation_location) {
            this.observation_location = observation_location;
        }

        public Estimated getEstimated() {
            return estimated;
        }

        public void setEstimated(Estimated estimated) {
            this.estimated = estimated;
        }

        public String getNowcast() {
            return nowcast;
        }

        public void setNowcast(String nowcast) {
            this.nowcast = nowcast;
        }
    }

    public Response getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(Response response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    public Current_observation getCurrent_observation() {
        return current_observation;
    }

    public void setCurrent_observation(Current_observation current_observation) {
        this.current_observation = current_observation;
    }
}
```

**Generate proper getter & setter**

Then in your main class create

```
Pojo model = new Pojo();
```

Call API & Parse the response

```
model = response.body(); // retrofit api call parsing
```

You have all your values ready to set

```
mEditText.setText(model.getCurrent_observation().image.url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to receive response as a JsonObject / JsonArray and parse it to create object with your own Model class.

So that you can avoid unwanted data, yes your code will be lengthy but its worth it. You can format and store the data. Easy to display.

Also "Opt" methods can be used instead of "Get", so NULL can be avoided.